# SwiftUI - How to add a pageTabView inside a scrollview with PinnedViews

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-scrollview

I had one problem while using SwiftUI. I have implemented a sectionHeader using PinnedView which is currently scrollable all up and down, has a header area, and is LazyVStack. Below is the implementation to show the corresponding content.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                Section {
                    Text("Header")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }

                Section {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(0...100, id: \.hashValue) { num in
                            Text("\(num)")
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()

                        Text("Section Header")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.black)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp0Uz.jpg

However, I did not stop here and declared a TabView to enable horizontal paging scrolling in the corresponding content area as shown below, but nothing was displayed in the Contents area.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                Section {
                    Text("Header")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }

                Section {

                    TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(0...100, id: \.hashValue) { num in
                                Text("A: \(num)")
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(0)

                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(0...100, id: \.hashValue) { num in
                                Text("B: \(num)")
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(1)
                    }

                } header: {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()

                        Text("Section Header")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color.black)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCzS6.jpg

I have found through debugging that if I declare a TabView inside a ScrollView, the Contents area doesn't show anything. Can you give me an idea on how to use the stickyHeader as in the above example to make it horizontally paging?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add These Modifiers to the TabView:

```
TabView {
...
}
.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```